# How to use Group By in play framework?

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I want to use Group By in play framework. Can someone tell me please how to use Group By in play framework?

Comment: do you mean scala groupBy, or SQL "group by"? Please provide additional details of what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: SQL "group by". I'm reading the play framework of the document now. 
  I want to 'find.where().groupBy("fieldname").findList()'. However, I did not find methods such as "groupBy".

Answer (score 1):

You can run **rawsql** for ex.

```
String sql   
    = " select order_id, o.status, c.id, c.name, sum(d.order_qty*d.unit_price) as totalAmount"  
    + " from o_order o"   
    + " join o_customer c on c.id = o.kcustomer_id "  
    + " join o_order_detail d on d.order_id = o.id "  
    + " group by order_id, o.status ";  

RawSql rawSql =   
    RawSqlBuilder  
        // let ebean parse the SQL so that it can  
        // add expressions to the WHERE and HAVING   
        // clauses  
        .parse(sql)  
        // map resultSet columns to bean properties  
        .columnMapping("order_id",  "order.id")  
        .columnMapping("o.status",  "order.status")  
        .columnMapping("c.id",      "order.customer.id")  
        .columnMapping("c.name",    "order.customer.name")  
        .create();  


Query<OrderAggregate> query = Ebean.find(OrderAggregate.class);  
    query.setRawSql(rawSql)          
    // add expressions to the WHERE and HAVING clauses  
    .where().gt("order.id", 0)  
    .having().gt("totalAmount", 20);  

List<OrderAggregate> list = query.findList();
```

> Note:Dont forget to import com.avaje.ebean.*;

[Source](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery_rawsql.html)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to use `GroupBy` in `Ebean` is using [SqlQuery](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html).

```
// Necessary imports..
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;

// SQL query.
String sql = "select max(salary) as maximum_salary, min(salary) as minimum_salary, department_id from employee_details where joining_date > :date group by department_id";

// Will get the list of Sql rows.
List<SqlRow> sqlRows = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).setParameter("date", "1995-10-21").findList();

// Getting first row of the list
SqlRow sql_row = sqlRows.get(0);

// Getting values of respective columns by using their name
int maximumSalary = sql_row.getInteger("maximum_salary");
int minimumSalary = sql_row.getInteger("minimum_salary");
int departmentID  = sql_row.getInteger("department_id");
```